# Baidu requesting malformed URLs - my fault or theirs?

Tags: web-crawlers, error, baidu

I often get lines like this in my error log:

```
2015/11/11 12:15:58 [error] 10927#0: *167859 open()
"/var/www/sites/mysite/http/https:/mysub.domain.com/filename.jpg"
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.125.71.113,
server: my.domain.com, request:
"GET /https:/mysub.domain.com/filename.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.com"
```

Which I think suggests two problems:

1) the missing slash

2) they're asking for

```
https://my.domain.com/https:/my.domain.com/filename.jpg
```

Or are they asking for

```
https:/mysub.domain.com/filename.jpg
```

Which despite the missing slash is managing to get resolved to my webserver, but still with the single slash?

I'm pretty sure this is Baidu's problem, and not mine.  Is this a common error?

Comment: The request would seem to be for: `https://my.domain.com/https:/mysub.domain.com/filename.jpg` - are `my` and `mysub` intended to be different? Which could occur if _you_ missed the double slash in a link, redirect, etc? Without the double slash after the protocol the URL is seen as _relative_. It's diffcult to imagine that Baidu would make this mistake, however, if that is the only source that these requests originate?!

Comment: The only one that's in my recent logs at least.  Yes, my & mysub are different.  If I've made the mistake myself it's certainly not current (and would be from MONTHS ago, if not longer).

Comment: Google Search Console presumably does not report any crawling errors?

Comment: What server are you using? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: Correct w3d.  Nginx Mike.  spdy, if that makes any odds.